# Can't match two different regex on split

Tags: java, regex, string, split

So I'm using a String as a delimiter to use when I call the Split method.

```
String[] aExpr;
String strDelimiter = "[-+/=^//%//*//(//);:?]"; 
aExpr = expr.split(strDelimiter);
```

This fills `aExpr` with the strings broken accordingly with the `strDelimiter`.

The thing is that I also want the `Split()` method to compare not only the `strDelimiter`, but also this String:

```
String oprDelimiter = "[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789]+"
```

Which is basically any characters followed by numbers. I could add all these characters to the First String, but the + in the end won't let me. The + means that any combination of the words will break the String. Any ideas of how could I do this?

Comment: Provide sample input and output.

Comment: Please show a sample string and the results you expect after applying the Split function

Comment: What I'm doing right now is using one delimiter and spliting it into one array, and then the other. After I Split both, I put them together in another array.
Lets say I input "1+3+5"
My aExpr array will have 1, 3, 5 and my aOpr array will have +, +
What I want is to have them already in just one array, so that I dont have to put them together later on. Was it clear?

Comment: It is clear now, you must use lookarounds as delimiters: `String strDelimiter = "(?=[-+/=^%*();:?])|(?<=[-+/=^%*();:?])";` Lookarounds (lookahead and lookbehind) are only checks for what is before or after a position in the string but don't consume characters. They are "zero-width assertions".

Comment: `//` doesn't seem right. If you mean escape sequence then you should use ``\\`` but you don't have to escape `%*()` inside `[...]` (character class).

Comment: You should be all set with comment from Casimir. @CasimiretHippolyte: You should convert your comment into an answer.

Comment: It works, awesome! Thanks a lot Casimir, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this regex:

```
(?<=[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789])(?=[-+=^%*();:?])|(?<=[-+=^%*();:?])(?=[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789])
```

as the delimiter. It will split on any location that is preceded by any of the characters `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789` and followed by any of the characters `-+=^%*();:?`, or vice versa. Explanation and demonstration here: http://regex101.com/r/mT3lL1.